# Agumented reality without marker for web application AR.js

Tags: web-applications, augmented-reality, ar.js

I'm trying to create **web application** with augmented reality using **AR.js**. I can successfully display objects with markers.

Is there any way to display augmented reality **without using marker** in AR.js.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible at the moment: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/190

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gone through in the ar.js code, I guess currently ar.js is rendering objects after detecting markers like hiro/kanji using patt files. We can even make changes in such a way that it detects custom markers and barcodes. But other than these, I dont think there is a way to render ar objects

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any way to display augmented reality without using marker in AR.js ?**

> Yes, display augmented reality without using marker in AR.js is possible by supporting Tango.
>
> For More Information please read : [AR.js application can now run without any markers!](https://medium.com/arjs/announcing-tango-support-for-ar-js-373572fec69e)